# How to validate recaptcha on comments form?

Tags: filters, comments, forms, captcha

I've added the following code to my function file to add the recaptcha, however I do not know how I can validate the captcha.

```
/**
* Add Captcha to Comments Form
 */
add_filter('comment_form', function() {
    echo '<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="'.GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SITEKEY.'"></div>';
});
```

Is there a filter for the submission of the comments form? I will be validating the captcha server side using the following:

> https://github.com/google/recaptcha

Any advise on how to implement the captcha to the comments form would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [`preprocess_comment`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/preprocess_comment) filter that is run before the comment is inserted in the database.

You will have access to the comment's data:

```
add_filter( 'preprocess_comment' , 'wpse321083_process_recaptcha' );
function wpse321083_process_recaptcha( $commentdata ) {
    // Process recaptcha here
    return $commentdata;
}
```

[Here's](https://www.sitepoint.com/integrating-a-captcha-with-the-wordpress-comment-form/) also a good article on [SitePoint.com](https://www.sitepoint.com/) explaining how to implement this feature in your website.